# JSON web token vulnerability with HMAC and RSA

Tags: web-application, cryptography, penetration-test, jwt

I'm currently learning about a vulnerability that takes advantage of a JSON web token which is discussed [here](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/)

Though I understood the nature of the bug and how it can be abused by attackers, I couldn't figure out how to exploit it. I have read many articles about it and came across a URL which can be used to test this vulnerability for educational purposes.  (You can find the two links for testing below.

---

[JSON security](http://demo.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/jwtdemo/rs256.php?)

[Public key](http://demo.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/jwtdemo/public.pem)

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can exploit this?

Comment: can anyone please shower your interest here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I bypassed it with custom JWT algorithm, where HMAC accepts public key as its secret key. Which cannot be done in python's **pyjwt** module or any other language since it is fixed.

Check out POC code [here](https://github.com/Goron1606/TokenBreaker/)